# Whatsapp Chat Anayzer with Python, what next?

Tags: python

im pretty new to python, and since learning information by just writing over the code the tutorial guy tells me I figured it would be better for me to actually build something, so I decided on a whatsapp chat analyzer.

I only got so far using google and now im stuck again. For the reference I use this website, which tells you how to make the chat analyzer but does not actually give you any code.

This is what I managed to do up until now, and that is, reading and printing out the .txt file.

```
f = open(r"chat.txt","r+", encoding='utf-8')
file_contents = f.read()
print(file_contents)
```

That just outputs the entire .txt file of chats.

Next, website says I should count the total number of messages and total number of words.

It suggest doing something aloing these lines:

Strings are treated as lists. So you can do a search like this:

```
if "- Paridhi:" in chat_line: 
counter+=1
```

Comment: By reading your post I am not sure what web you refer to. Also the identation for the code on the if is not right, you need to put 4 spaces before counter and also give a first value cto counter. The variable chat_line is not declared. If you need help you should provide more information also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define `counter=0`

Just like this:

```
splt=file_contents.split()
print(splt)
counter=0
if 'file' in splt:
    counter=counter+1
print(counter)
```